# Can I send dynamic messages with the Facebook send button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins

I would like to allow my users to invite their friend through Facebook private message to earn some rewards. I am wondering if it is possible to do it using the facebook send button. Sadly I found that the send button can only send a static url (such as www.website.com). However, I'd like to append different arguments from person to person (such as www.website.com/invite.php?token=tk12345) to the url. Any ideas?

Comment: _“Sadly I found that the send button can only send a static url”_ – what gave you that idea? – _“However, I'd like to append different arguments from person to person (such as www.website.com/invite.php?token=tk12345) to the url.”_ – that’s what we are doing in one of our apps, and it’s working perfectly fine. You just have to make sure that that URL is publicly reachable by Facebook’s scraper.

Comment: That's great. Can you share a little bit more how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: I also want one receiver receives one unique url (i.e. no two receivers can receive a same url). Do you have any ideas? Many Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<fb:send id="mysendbtn" href="www.website.com"></fb:send>
<script>
    $("#mysendbtn").attr("href", "www.website.com/invite.php?token=tk12345");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. BTW, is it also possible to restrict the number of receiver to 1 so that no two receivers get the same url or same token?